# Factor Analysis...Covariance Matrix help

Tags: spss, factor-analysis, covariance, matrix

I'm trying to run a factor analysis in SPSS on a set of social vulnerability data for my thesis. I have 5 communities, with 26 social vulnerability variables for each community. My overall aim is to determine the number of components and their respective variables that the data can be reduced into.

When I run the Factor Analysis, SPSS tells me my covariance matrix is "not positive definite." There are a few high correlations in my matrix (r > 0.900), so I removed the variables that were involved in these high correlations, but still get the same "not positive definite" issue. I tried continually removing more variables that were strongly correlated and had to go down to r = 0.70 but  the "not positive definite" message continues to appear. I am running out of variables to remove, as my dataset keeps reducing in size, everytime i eliminate a variable!

My understanding is that the not positive definite problem should only arise if you have near-perfect collinearity between one or more variables.

If so, is there some kind of stepwise way of dealing with the problem, rather than just arbitrarily removing variables until the problem goes away? ( which i have tried to do but is very futile) IS something wrong with my data ??(I have converted the raw data into z scores to run this analysis)

Any help is much appreciated!

PS I do not have a statistical background..I am studying Geoinformatics!

Comment: High correlations shouldn't matter. Are you using pairwise deletion of missing values? That can cause the covariance matrix to not be positive definite.

Comment: [this article](http://www2.gsu.edu/~mkteer/npdmatri.html) covers a lot of possible causes and cures of NPD matrices

Comment: Hi Mark, no I am not using pairwise deletion of missing data

I am thinking to do a multicollinearity test on my data...hopefully i mkake some progress..

Comment: Hi Peter, I came agroos that article!! thats how i deduced my matrix was not linear dependent.im not to sure how I go about fixing it

Comment: When you say you have 5 communities with 26 social vulnerability variables do you mean that there are 5 cases in the data and 26 variables for each case? If so, it's likely that you're running into a problem due to small sample size. Also, if your purpose is to reduce the number of variables and determine number of components you should consider Principal Component Analysis. The purpose of PCA is specifically to help reduce the number of observed variables necessary to explain variability.